# I am getting an error of Html Webpack Plugin in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My Application was working fine but when I installed material ui npm package my application is giving me this error.

```
 Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
  Error: [BABEL] C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\b  uildin\global.js: Cannot find module './src/data'
  Require stack:
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\core-js-compat\helpers  .js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\core-js-compat\get-mod  ules-list-for-target-version.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app  \node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\polyfills\corejs3\entry-plugin.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app  \node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app  \dependencies.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config  \files\plugins.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config  \files\index.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.  js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index  .js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\load  Loader.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\Load  erRunner.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModu  le.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModu  leFactory.js
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.j  s
  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js  - C:\ReactJS work\React Projects\portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\  start.js (While processing: "C:\\ReactJS work\\React Projects\\portfolio\\node  _modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\dependencies.js$0$9")

  - loader.js:794 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15

  - loader.js:687 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27

  - loader.js:849 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19
```

Comment: Do you have or intend to have a file such as `data.js` or similar that you are trying to import and use in your code?

Comment: Can you upload your webpack config file please? It would also be helpful to see your package.json file

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky No, I don't want to add any data.js file. I just started to make this. It was working well initially but when just I installed material ui npm it crashes

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there's been a bad build of npm package `core-js-compat`. This is a deep-down dependency of Babel. Lots of things will be affected, things that use Babel. It's not specifically to do with material-ui -- you were just unfortunate to update your npm package versions while a bad build was live.

You will experience the problem if you have core-js-compat v.3.4.6. You can check this by doing `npm list core-js-compat`. The problem is apparently fixed by v.3.4.7, which was pushed out pretty quickly, about half-an-hour later, but unfortunately it takes a while to spread out through the repositories. You can either wait until an `npm update` gets you v.3.4.7 or you can go manually download v.3.4.7 if you want to get going right away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. I realized I am using node.js version 12.13.0, However New version 12.13.1 is already released. So I just updated my node js and my app is now working fine and not showing any issues.