# Html Webpack Plugin: Child Compilation Failed error in React page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React, and I'm following a tutorial, and after a 'yarn start' command, I go to 'localhost:3000' and see this error appear:

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
  Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\glob  al.js: Cannot find module './src/data'
```

It's the first step of the tutorial that has anything to do with React at all, so I don't see where could I have gone wrong, any ideas on what the problem might be would be very useful.

The full error is this:

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
  Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\glob  al.js: Cannot find module './src/data'
  Require stack:
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\core-js-compat\helpers.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\core-js-compat\get-modules-list-f  or-target-version.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_modul  es\@babel\preset-env\lib\polyfills\corejs3\entry-plugin.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_modul  es\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\dependenci  es.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plug  ins.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\inde  x.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.j  s
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
  - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js (W  hile processing: "C:\\Users\\Iván\\PycharmProjects\\django_react\\django-todo-react\\frontend\\node_modules\\babel-pre  set-react-app\\dependencies.js$0$9")

  - loader.js:797 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15

  - loader.js:690 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27

  - loader.js:852 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19

  - helpers.js:74 require
    internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18

  - helpers.js:3 Object.
    [frontend]/[core-js-compat]/helpers.js:3:14

  - loader.js:959 Module._compile
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30

  - loader.js:995 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10

  - loader.js:815 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32

  - loader.js:727 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14

  - loader.js:852 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19

  - helpers.js:74 require
    internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18

  - get-modules-list-for-target-version.js:2 Object.
    [frontend]/[core-js-compat]/get-modules-list-for-target-version.js:2:51

  - loader.js:959 Module._compile
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30

  - loader.js:995 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10

  - loader.js:815 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32
- Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\gl    obal.js: Cannot find module './src/data'

  - Require stack:

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\core-js-compat\helpers.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\core-js-compat\get-modules-list    -for-target-version.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_mod    ules\@babel\preset-env\lib\polyfills\corejs3\entry-plugin.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_mod    ules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\dependen    cies.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\pl    ugins.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\in    dex.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js  
  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.    js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory    .js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js     (While processing: "C:\\Users\\Iván\\PycharmProjects\\django_react\\django-todo-react\\frontend\\node_modules\\babel    -preset-react-app\\dependencies.js$0$9")

  - Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

  - Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\mo    dule.js: Cannot find module './src/data'

  - Require stack:

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\core-js-compat\helpers.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\core-js-compat\get-modules-list    -for-target-version.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_mod    ules\@babel\preset-env\lib\polyfills\corejs3\entry-plugin.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\node_mod    ules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\dependen    cies.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\pl    ugins.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\in    dex.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js  
  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.    js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory    .js

  - - C:\Users\Iván\PycharmProjects\django_react\django-todo-react\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
```

I see three errors in total, all saying "Cannot find module './src/data'", so I guess there's that missing? In my project directory, I don't see anything called 'data' in the 'src' folder. Why could that be, or what should I add to fix it?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144633/i-am-getting-an-error-of-html-webpack-plugin-in-reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

temporary fix until the core-js-compat makes its way through all the repos:

```
npm i -s core-js-compat@3.4.7
```

Apparently this is related to a bad build of core-js-compat, which is a deep dependency of babel.  These two posts have more information:

[Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module './src/data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145601/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js-error-cann)

[I am getting an error of Html Webpack Plugin in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144633/i-am-getting-an-error-of-html-webpack-plugin-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a bug in the core-js-combat version 3.4.6. This nasty bug is already fixed in version 3.4.7. So you can run `npm install core-js-compat@3.4.7 --save` .

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me you can also try this

```
npm install core-js-compat@3.4.7 --save
```